# UIKit Dynamic spring back slightly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit

How can this effect be achieved with `UIDynamicAnimator`?

**Layout:**

`------[uiview]-------->-------|anchor point|---<---[edge]`

**Interaction:**

- User can drag object past anchor point but it will slide to anchor point.
- User can swipe right to anchor point but if velocity is high, the object will move slightly past it and bounce back to anchor point.